# Oracle SQL Nested Case When Invalid Number of Arguments

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have 3 levels nested `case when` statements, I made sure every case has its own `else end`, but still gives me error `invalid number of arguments`, what's wrong here other than nested functions and undefined parameter ?

```
case when cnumber > 999999999999.99 then 'Please enter a number less than 1 Trillion (1,000,000,000,000.00).'
    else case when ((ROUND(CNUMBER, 2) - TRUNC(CNUMBER, 0)) * 100) > 0 THEN
        case when TRUNC(CNUMBER, 0) = 0 then 
            case when ((ROUND(CNUMBER, 2) - TRUNC(CNUMBER, 0)) * 100) = 1 then 
            REPLACE(REPLACE(fraction(FR) || ' ' || fakat, '   ', ' '), '  ', ' ')
            else  REPLACE(REPLACE(fraction(FR), '   ', ' '), '  ', ' ') end
        ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(anumb(TR) || ' و' || fraction(FR), '   ', ' '), '  ', ' ') end
    else REPLACE(REPLACE(anumb(TR) || ' ' || fakat, '   ', ' '), '  ', ' ') end
else 'function numb. Others. Ex.' end
```

Comment: the else from the last line is already set in the second, so that there must only be a END

Comment: I recommend laying out code neatly, especially when it gets complicated like this. If you place each `case`/`end` keyword on its own line and align them vertically then typos like this will become obvious and easy to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you formatted it somewhat better, you'd notice what nbk commented:

```
SQL> select
  2  case when cnumber > 999999999999.99 then
  3           'Please enter a number less than 1 Trillion (1,000,000,000,000.00).'
  4  *    else case when ((ROUND(CNUMBER, 2) - TRUNC(CNUMBER, 0)) * 100) > 0 THEN
  5                      case when TRUNC(CNUMBER, 0) = 0 then
  6                                case when ((ROUND(CNUMBER, 2) - TRUNC(CNUMBER, 0)) * 100) = 1 then
  7                                           REPLACE(REPLACE(fraction(FR) || ' ' || fakat, '   ', ' '), '  ', ' ')
  8                                     else  REPLACE(REPLACE(fraction(FR), '   ', ' '), '  ', ' ')
  9                                end
 10                           ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(anumb(TR) || ' و' || fraction(FR), '   ', ' '), '  ', ' ')
 11                      end
 12                 else REPLACE(REPLACE(anumb(TR) || ' ' || fakat, '   ', ' '), '  ', ' ')
 13            end
 14  *    else 'function numb. Others. Ex.'
 15  end
 16  from ...
```

See asterisks in lines #4 and 14? I marked two `ELSE`s of the same `CASE`.

I don't know what you meant to do. The last `ELSE` looks like an *exception* which is supposed to be displayed of something unexpected has happened. But, where? All `CASE`s have their `ELSE`s which means that you already handled "other" cases, so it seems as if line #14 is suprefluous and should be removed from the expression.